# Sorting a list of checkBoxOption Error: One or more of the items in this list is not Comparable

Tags: apex, visualforce, controller

I am attempting to sort a list a list in my class however I am running into the error above. The list comes from a method in another class.

```
public static List< vCtrl.CheckboxOption> convertPicklistValuesIntoCheckBox( Map<String, SobjectField> fieldMap,String fieldName){

        Schema.DescribeFieldResult legacy = fieldMap.get(fieldName).getDescribe();
        List<Schema.PicklistEntry> legacySeries= legacy.getPicklistValues();
        List< vCtrl.CheckboxOption> listOfCheckBoxOption = new List< vCtrl.CheckboxOption>();
        for (Schema.PicklistEntry entry : legacySeries) 
        {
            vCtrl.CheckboxOption boxOption = new  vCtrl.CheckboxOption();
            boxOption.label = entry.getLabel();
            boxOption.value = entry.getValue();
            boxOption.selected = false;
            listOfCheckBoxOption.add(boxOption);
        }    

        return listOfCheckBoxOption;
    }
```

I am using the list below in class vCtrl and want it sorted alphabetically. Calling List.sort() method on this list throws error: **One or more of the items in this list is not Comparable.**

```
listMake  =  Utill.convertPicklistValuesIntoCheckBox(fieldMap,'Make__c');
listMake.sort();
```

Comment: What are the list values?

Comment: Can you show us the class vCtrl.CheckboxOption ?

Answer (score 1):

Not knowing how your CheckboxOption class looks like I try to answer using some assumptions:

Let's assume your class looks like this:

```
public class CheckboxOption {
    public Boolean selected { get; set; }
    public String label { get; set; }
    public String value { get; set; }
}
```

You need to make it implement the interface Comparable:

```
public class CheckboxOption implements Comparable {
    public Boolean selected { get; set; }
    public String label { get; set; }
    public String value { get; set; }

    public Integer compareTo(Object compareTo) {
        CheckboxOption other = (CheckboxOption)compareTo;
        return this.label.compareTo(other.label);
}
```

Haven't tested this snippet, but you should get the idea.

Answer (score 0):

This error occurs because one or more of them items in your list is not comparable. To make comparison work the objects in list must implement `Comparable` interface.

Only primitives, SelectOption, and sObjects can be cmpared and here you are doing something with Schema I guess which isn't supported.